# Update multiple rows at once google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

happy new year !

I have a issue with this code.

I would like update multiple rows at once but, my code works just for the first one.

Could you help me please ?

```
function majsdemandeadv() {
  //declare a variable and set with active google sheet 
  var myGooglSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

  //delcare a variable and set with the User Form worksheet  
  var shUserForm= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Gestion des emails et des courriers"); 

  //delcare a variable and set with the Database worksheet
  var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Globale"); /
  var str       = shUserForm.getRange("A4:A").getValue();

  //getting the entire values from the used range and assigning it to values variable
  var values    = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    //declaraing a variable and storing the value
    var rowValue = values[i]; 
   
    //checking the first value of the record is equal to search item
    if (rowValue[2] == str) {  
      //identify the row number
      var  iRow = i + 1;
      datasheet.getRange(iRow, 14).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("S4:S").getValue());

      //Clearnign the data from the Data Entry Form
      //shUserForm.getRange("B1").clear(); //Search Field
  
      valuesFound=true;
      return; //come out from the search function     
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: The data in ("S4:S") is the same for all entries.

Answer (score 0):

You are exiting the loop after first successfully passed condition with :
`return; //come out from the search function`

Comment: Thanks Ricardas, but that doesn't change anything. :(